# Line-up horizontally social icons with "Facebook", "Twitter" and "Linkedin" button

Tags: css, icons

I have some problems to align my social icons buttons horizontally and have not found any satisfying response to my issue.

I have the "Facebook", "Twitter" and "Linkedin" buttons, but the one of "Facebook" doesn't seem to react when I try to change it with a css code.

I just want "Facebook" button to be aligned with the "Twitter" and "Linkedin" button.

Here are the PHP codes in my PHP file:

```html
<div id="fb-root"><hr/></div>
<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-href="<?php the_permalink()?>" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100"data-show-faces="false"></div>
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
 lang: en_US
</script>
<script type="IN/Share"></script>
```

And here are the CSS codes that I put in my CSS file:

```css
.fb-like{float:left;display:block;}
.twitter-share-button{float:left;}
```

Comment: Not regarding your question, when you go to about or articles you have a minor problem. When you hover over the dropdown on the corresponding page the text is white making it unable to be read unless that link has an active hover state.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I find that the easiest way to do this is to wrap every individual social plugin in a div, and then float those divs instead of trying to float the plugins. Then, you can even apply widths and padding and everything to position them exactly how you want it.

Answer (score 1):

For horizontal layouts, you could try to use inline styling.  Set the display for every item to inline-block like this:

```
.fb-like{display:inline-block;}
.twitter-share-button{display:inline-block;}
```

Then you can use the vertical-align css property to tell them to align based on their tops, bottoms, or middles. Like this:

```
.fb-like{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;}
.twitter-share-button{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;}
```

Also, in order for these css properties to work, you are going to have to set the position and remove the attribute:

```
float: left;
```

Set the position property with this:

```
position:static;
```

or this

```
position: relative;
```

Answer (score 1):

i have followed the sugesttion from @KateNickerson but i also have to add a fixed width of 100px for the facebook share button to display correctly inline.

```
<div style="width: 100px;float:left">
    <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://.../" data-layout="button_count"></div>
</div>

<div style="width: 100px;float:left; margin-top: 2px;">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>
    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
</div>
```